# How to Initialize or call Vanilla Datatables in .NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc

I,am designing cshtml pages using
As per the instructions given here, https://github.com/Mobius1/Vanilla-DataTables

I have added CSS and JS files appropriately,

**CSS**

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vanilla-datatables@latest/dist/vanilla-dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vanilla-datatables@latest/dist/vanilla-dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I tried to initialize the table in my index page by calling below code in my cshtml index page

```
<script>
var table = new DataTable("table");
</script>
```

Also tried

```
<script>
var table = new DataTable("#datatable");
</script>
```

where table is my table class name and datatable is the id of the table. But nothing shows up. Please let me know if you require any additional details. I,am using .net core and bootstrap in MVC architecture.

#### Edit

Based on the provided answer, I ended up using simple datatables from referred in the same Github repo as a solution which is the latest iteration of vanilla datatables:

https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables

And initialised using below script at bottom of the cshtml page:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-datatables@latest"></script>
<script>
    // Simple Datatable
    var mytable = document.querySelector('#datatable');
    var dataTable = new simpleDatatables.DataTable(mytable,{
    
//Enter any additional config details required here if required. Else Leave Blank

    });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be related to .net, nor does it relate to bootstrap that i can see. So its probably better if you remove those tags and mentions in the title. If you can also show your html code that would be helpful.

Comment: @Achtung I have removed bootstrap tag, Please do note my project is in .NET Core MVC, hence I have included .net core tags, I need to know how would I call the vanilla datatables in a .net core application.

Comment: You didn't post an HTML source. Are you sure you have the HTML element with the same ID datatable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Vanilla-DataTables` repo you linked to has several links with examples using their scripts.

The value used in the `DataTable` .ctor appears to be the class name of the HTML table(s) to bind `Vanilla-DataTables`.

So, in your example, if you use:

```js
<script>
var table = new DataTable("table");
</script>
```

Then you need to have an HTML `table` with a css class named `table`:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Ext.</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th data-type="date" data-format="YYYY/MM/DD">Start Date</th>
            <th>Completion</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Unity Pugh</td><td>9958</td><td>Curicó</td><td>2005/02/11</td><td>37%</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Theodore Duran</td><td>8971</td><td>Dhanbad</td><td>1999/04/07</td><td>97%</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Kylie Bishop</td><td>3147</td><td>Norman</td><td>2005/09/08</td><td>63%</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Alisa Horn</td><td>9853</td><td>Ucluelet</td><td>2007/01/11</td><td>39%</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Zelenia Roman</td><td>7516</td><td>Redwater</td><td>2012/03/03</td><td>31%</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Source: [Vanilla-DataTable Demos](https://github.com/Mobius1/Vanilla-DataTables#demos) > [Default Setup](https://codepen.io/Mobius1/pen/VadmKb)

Comment: Many Thanks ! for sharing the example. This led me in finding a solution to my project. Ended up using Simple Datatables referred to in the same Github repo. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Checking on how to select what columns need searching. Not sure how to customize and choose columns that can be searched.

Comment: @ahp If the answer helped you: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)